# Most general polynomial of 2 or 3 variables and degree 4 with at least 4 minima

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

I am searching for the most general (if any) real polynomial that has the following features:

-Degree 4

-$m+n$ variables, with $m \ge 2$ and $n \ge 0$ (focusing on $m=2, n=1$)

-It is even in the first $m \ge 2$ variables $P(x,y,z_i)=P(-x,y,z_i)=P(x,-y,z_i)$

-The following limit holds: $\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} P(x,y,z_i) = +\infty$ where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2 +\sum_i z_i^2}$

-Has at least 4 minima (ideally 2 symmetric minima for $x=0, y=\pm A_1, z_i=B_{1,i}$ and 2 symmetric minima for $x= \pm A_2, y=0, z_i=B_{2,i}$, with $A_{1,2} \neq 0$)

-The 2 minima have different values for $P$: $P(0,A_1,B_{1,i}) \neq P(A_2,0,B_{2,i})$

The point $(0,0,z_i)$ is not a minima, or if it is a minima then $P(0,0,z_i) \ge MIN[P(0,A_1,B_{1,i}), P(A_2,0,B_{2,i})]$